# Error al mover archivo python

Tags: python, librería

Soy relativamente nuevo en python, la idea del programa que estoy haciendo es que el programa lea la metadata de las imágenes y basado en el modelo del teléfono por el cual fue tomada la foto la almacene en una lista para después mover los elementos de la lista a una carpeta, sin embargo me da un error. Ademas de esto solo mueve una de las fotos, la que contiene el data == 'Apple', las demas no las mueve. Agradecería cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme. Muchas gracias!

Este seria mi codigo

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import glob
import shutil
import os

apple_list = []
huawei_list = []
ps4_list = []

for name in sorted(glob.glob('*.jpg')):
    image = Image.open(name)
    exifdata = image.getexif()
    for tag_id in exifdata:
        tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
        data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
        if data == 'Apple':
            apple_list.append(name)
        elif data == 'HUAWEI':
            huawei_list.append(name)
        else:
            ps4_list.append(name)

for value in apple_list:
    source = value
    destination = 'C:\Galery\Apple'
    new_path = shutil.move(source, destination)

for value in huawei_list:
    source = value
    destination = 'C:\Galery\HUAWEI'
    new_path = shutil.move(source, destination)

for value in ps4_list:
    source = value
    destination = 'C:\Galery\PS4'
    new_path = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Y este seria el error que me da:

> "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe"
> C:/Users/RicardoPerezPerez/PycharmProjects/Proyecto/ejemplo_move.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/RicardoPerezPerez/PycharmProjects/Proyecto/ejemplo_move.py",
> line 40, in 
> new_path = shutil.move(source, destination)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 555, in move
> raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst) shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\Galery\Apple\IMG_9569.JPG' already
> exists
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

**Problema:**

> Destination path 'C:\Galery\Apple\IMG_9569.JPG' already exists

Es decir, ya habías ejecutado este mismo *script* previamente y se te creó el archivo o tu *script* lee 2 imágenes con el mismo nombre y las intenta poner en la misma carpeta, tal que le salta que ya existe este archivo.

**Solución:**

Una posible solución es añadir un `if` o `while` que verifique si la imagen ya existe y le añada un sufijo: `value = '.'.join(value.split('.')[0:-1]) + sufijo + '.jpg'`. Esto te permitiría hacer una prueba y ver si tu problema es que tienes varias imágenes bajo el mismo nombre o si se te está copiando la misma imagen varias veces.

Comment: Muchas gracias @MrJavy, probe tu solucion y me resulto muy bien tambien.

Answer (score 2):

Ampliando la solución de @MrJavy te puedo dar dos soluciones:

### 1. Chequear si existe

Puedes crear un `if` para ver si existe el archivo. Y elegir que hacer en cada caso.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from pathlib import Path
#Introducimos la URL que queremos verificar su existencia
archivo_x = Path("/url/al/archivo_x")

#Si el archivo que queremos mover no existe, entonces lo movemos.
if not archivo_x.exist():
    source = value
    destination = 'C:\Galery\Apple'
    new_path = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

El método `exist()` te devuelve un booleano. En el caso de que el archivo no exista lo mueves, si existe no hace falta moverlo porque ya lo tienes!

### 2. Copiar

sustituyendo `shutil.move()` por `shutil.copy()` en el código. Esta función sobreescribe automáticamente los ficheros (sobreescribe), pero no copia o crea directorios, por lo que tienes que asegurarte de que existan previamente (que es como los tienes ahora).

Comment: Perfecto @Rubiales Alberto tu sugerencia me funciono con lo que queria, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de ser de ayuda!! Aunque como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow en marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" la de @MrJavy o la mia, y por qué no, dar un voto positivo (cuando tengas experiencia).